# How to fix "value error bad transparency mask"?

Tags: python, image, generator

****This error is for line 1525 in the PIL image.py which is self.im.paste (im, box, mask.im)  at the bottom of this post.****

def paste(self, im, box=None, mask=None):

```
    if isImageType(box) and mask is None:
        # abbreviated paste(im, mask) syntax
        mask = box
        box = None

    if box is None:
        box = (0, 0)

    if len(box) == 2:
        # upper left corner given; get size from image or mask
        if isImageType(im):
            size = im.size
        elif isImageType(mask):
            size = mask.size
        else:
            # FIXME: use self.size here?
            raise ValueError("cannot determine region size; use 4-item box")
        box += (box[0] + size[0], box[1] + size[1])

    if isinstance(im, str):
        from . import ImageColor

        im = ImageColor.getcolor(im, self.mode)

    elif isImageType(im):
        im.load()
        if self.mode != im.mode:
            if self.mode != "RGB" or im.mode not in ("RGBA", "RGBa"):
                # should use an adapter for this!
                im = im.convert(self.mode)
        im = im.im

    self._ensure_mutable()

    **if mask:
        mask.load()
        self.im.paste (im, box, mask.im)
    else:
        self.im.paste(im, box)**
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and bring the code down to a [mcve]?

Comment: It's not necessary to post the source code of `Image.paste` to show where the failure. Just show your short and executable code to demo the failure and also the exception information.